# 1995 Toyota Tacoma V6 4WD 5-speed manual - front differential drain

Tags: tacoma

Yesterday I was changing the oil on my front differential for the first time and mistakenly opened a drain bolt on the passenger side of the front differential:
[image: passenger side front diff drain]

I then figured out the proper drain bolt and opened it (and labeled it):
[image: driver side front diff drain]

The filler bolt is on the front of the differential, up higher than the drain bolts of course:
[image: filler hole front diff]

It looked to me like the same oil came out of both drain holes. Does anyone know what the passenger side hole is for?

Comment: Presumably no more oil came out when you removed the second drain plug?

Comment: @HandyHowie, good question - I should have mentioned that. It's hard to tell from the pictures, but the passenger side hole is a little higher than the driver's side hole, so when I opened the driver's side hole, more oil did drain out.